# Java - How to access Windows Registry remotely

Tags: java, registry, remote-access

I found that it is possible to access Windows Registry remotely using [C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But is it possible to do remote Windows Registry access through **JAVA**?

Just be able to read the registry remotely would be helpful!

**EDIT**

Here is how to edit Windows Registry locally. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Comment: JNI apart, i know its possible to do all sorts of manipulations on remote windows hosts using plain java. for example, jenkins can install and start windows services from *nix machines, but im not familiar with the code itself

Answer (score 1):

Using [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) you can make calls to native APIs.  Using that, you could call the Windows API function you cited.